# real-time notification if is not online

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

scenario: When user 1 assigns a user 2 to a task user 2 will receive a notıfication

how can I realize it?

do I have to store the notification in the database then send it to user2 then remove it after he sees it. but with this, I think he will need to refresh the page to get notified
,or there is any other logic to do it?

using:
nodejs mongoDb mongoose

Comment: You'd need sockets to do that. Check this [link](https://socket.io/docs/v4/)

Comment: if the user is not online?

Comment: You will need sockets to send notifications so that the user doesn't need to refresh the page to see the notification.

Comment: If I were to deal with this problem, I'd create a notification schema with `isSeen` field (defaults to false) and the ObjectID of the notification. Once the user sees the notification, the isSeen property is put to `true`. Based on the `isSeen` status I'd apply active and inactive classes.

Comment: That same as what I thinking but the problem it is not efficient for long period. because the server has to check for all the notifications and this is time-wasting

Comment: For the 'not online' part you need to use Send Web Push Notifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem by creating a notification schema with isSeen field (defaults to false) and the ObjectID of the notification. Once the user sees the notification, the isSeen property is put to true. Based on the isSeen status I'd apply active and inactive classes.